# How to add custom meta box under Gallery Settings in the "Edit Gallery" popup

Tags: theme-development, gallery, media-settings

I am developing a theme.

I want to add option for the user to choose the type of the gallery which he is adding. Will it be a slider, masonry gallery or some other type.

I cannot figure it out how I can add custom meta data in the media popup. Here in the screenshot I am showing where I would like to put it.

[image]

I would like to add SELECT, with OPTIONs of the Gallery type.

Thank you